# Runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.0.0....Azure mobile services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, owin, azure-mobile-services

I have downloaded the ToDOService project from the Azure managementprotal after I created a Mobile service. Initially it had a lot of errors as the Nuget packages were outdated. I Uninstalled the `Azure mobile services .net backend` package and its dependencies. Later I again installed all the packages manually and then I could build the project successfully. Somehow, when I run the service project I get this error:-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 18: 
Line 19:             // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
Line 20:             HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
Line 21: 
Line 22:             // To display errors in the browser during development, uncomment the following

Source File: ...\MyProject\MyService\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs    Line: 20
```

My web.config looks like this

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

I also tried to update the assembly to the latest, but could not be updated as Ver 3.0.1 is not compatible with its other dependencies.

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this issue, [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2013/11/20/fileloadexception-on-microsoft-owin-when-running-on-worker-role.aspx) says that it happens when a SignalR or Web API application runs in a worker role. For me, this error happens after I run a console app that is part of my solution...next time I try to access a web application in  the project that uses Web API, I get the yellow screen of death.

The fix mentioned in the blog post does not work, it appears your web.config has the correct version information specified. It sounds like this is still an issue with the NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue, and apperantly by updating the Microsoft.Owin to the latest version (The time of writing this Version 3.0.1.0) solve the problem.

You can upgrade the package using package manager console, and type:
"Install-Package Microsoft.Owin"

Hope it helps.